# associate the user with the post Django and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

I am trying to associate the user with the post. I have two models ***students*** is for user and ***sublists*** is for user posts with a ***foreign key(author)***. I am using MySQL database and using forms to store data into them. when my form.author execute in my HTML file it gives me a list of ids for all users in the databse but I am already logged in and i want to post as the logged in user without choosing. If remove it says my form is not valid which make sense since im not inputing for form.author.Since I'm using MySQL, I'm not using the built-in User authentication method, but instead comparing both email and password with the login form input. Spend too much time on this but hard to get around with this one. Any help would be appreciated

**my views.py look like this**

```
def addnew(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Sublist(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ' Subscirption Saved')
            name = sublist.objects.get(name=name)
            return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'sublist': name})
        except:
            pass
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Error')
        pass
else:
    form = Sublist()
return render(request, 'subscrap/addnew.html', {'form': form})


@login_required(login_url='login')
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True) 
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'subscrap/main.html')
    


def mod(request):
    student = students.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'subscrap/mod.html' , {'students': student})
```

**My Models.py**

```
class students(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = True)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "students"

class sublist(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(students, related_name='sublist' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    renewalcycle = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "sublist"
```

Since I'm using forms here's my **forms.py**

```
lass StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = students
        fields = "__all__"

class Studentlogin(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    
class Sublist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = sublist
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Is student the user model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes students is user model

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `Author` from the `Sublist` form:

```
class Sublist(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = sublist
        exclude = ['author']
```

In the `addnew` method, you associate the `.instance.author` with the `request.user`:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def addnew(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Sublist(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ' Subscirption Saved')
            return redirect('some_view')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error')
    else:
        form = Sublist()
    return render(request, 'subscrap/addnew.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`sublist`</s> to `Sublist`.

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `SublistForm` instead of
> <s>`Sublist`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the `students` directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you for your well written response, i did what u mentioned but it gives me this error " 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'" or whatever i put instead of user.

Comment: @zayan21: well then likely did not use the [`AuthenticationMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) as middleware: this is supposed to add the logged in user (`student` in this case) to the request object.

Comment: @zayant21: and likely your `students` model can not be a user model, since it is missing some of the necessary features: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I am sorry it's my first web app project. :) I am looking into that I am trying to search more about the User-authenticate method so i can use it. Ty for your help Willem